# Speeding up Tweepy application

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I am relatively new to Python and I have written this python application that downloads from twitter all the available tweets of a user (3200) and creates a csv file with a series of details on the tweets. I'll post a snippet to give you a clearer picture:

```
 import tweepy
 import codecs
 import requests
 import csv

 auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("xxx", "xxx")
 auth.set_access_token("xxx", "xxx")

 with open("file", mode='wb') as f:
  writer=csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
  headers= ['id','username','date','status','lang','source', 'place', 'coordinates', 'in_reply_to_screen_name', 'retweet_count', 'favorite_count', 'hashtags','urls', 'retweeted_status', 'retweeted_hashtags', 'retweeted_urls'] 
  writer.writerow(headers)
  api = tweepy.API(auth)
  for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, "x",include_entities=True).items():
    row=[]

    row.append(format(status.id).encode('utf-8'))
    ...
    ...
    ...

    urls=""
    for url in status.entities['urls']:
        expanded_url=url['expanded_url']
        r= requests.head(expanded_url)
        if r.status_code in range (200,300):
            urltext=format(r.url)
        elif r.status_code in range (300,400):
            urltext=format(r.headers['location'])
        else:
            urltext=format(r.status_code)
        urls=urls+urltext+" "
    row.append(format(urls).encode('utf-8'))
    ...
    ...
    ...  

    writer.writerow(row)
```

The code works but it has a runtime of over 30 minutes which is way too long considering that this needs to be iterated over a list of users. Is there a way I can speed it up? I have read about C libraries and Pypy(but I have version 2.7) but I could find nothing about a compatibility with tweepy. What kind of approach should I take? Is there a library I should be aware of?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: There's a lot of stuff going on here - have you profiled it to see where the time is going?  (see [this intro to python profiling](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html))

Comment: This might be a better fit on the Code Review site since it is working code.